# Are there any benefits of computable analysis to numerical algorithms

Tags: numerical-analysis, convergence, approximation

Computers can work only with [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), while most of the algorithms are based on analysis of real numbers (real analysis).

When I heard of the existence of [computable analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis) I immediately had these questions:

- Can it help numerical analysis in some way?
- Can we for example, help prove convergence of algorithms that are not convergent in the reals?
- Can we find different algorithms that work for computables faster than they do for reals?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's strictly relevant to your question, but you might want to consider [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) too. Although I guess that's really attacking a similar problem from an engineering viewpoint.

Comment: Yes, interval arithmetic is useful but conceptually it's not hard. Computable analysis seems to try to reinvent all of algebra for computers.